# Store code url not changed by saving from backend as well as change value in database(core_config_data)

Tags: magento-1.8, store-code

[image]

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=0 WHERE path='web/url/use_store' and scope_id=0
```

i want to remove store code from website url but it doesn't work. even i change value in database and it revert to previous after change. it solved problem initially but it revert it value automatic.

Comment: Did you flush cache from admin? removed var/cache/* ?

Comment: @Nidheesh  yes but it revert it value automatic

Comment: Did you check your /tmp directory in your server? Check and see whether you can see any magento related files/directories

Comment: @Nidheesh No there's only batch-.tmp files

Comment: Are you usingn any other caching other than default file cache?

Comment: @Nidheesh  No. 
1 . i want to know why it couldn't save from backend. how can i debug error/issue if other extension conflict

Comment: Its hard to explain how to debug as it may depend on what all extension installed in your magento.

Comment: @Nidheesh I disable  output of all third party extension but problem remain same..

Comment: Disabling output of 3rd party modules will not disable that modules. In order to disable 3rd party modules, you need to do that it in /etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml

Comment: or you can disable all local modules in your local.xml

Comment: @Nidheesh  ok   i disable  all from local.xml. but problem remain same..

Comment: Share your local.xml by masking the credentials..

Comment: <disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>   add it in local.xml file